# How to create paged tables in a loop in R rmarkdown?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr, kable

Below I'm trying show a [`paged_table`](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/rmarkdown/reference/paged_table.html) below each plot in my loop.

But the tables don't show up at all. I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this in Rmarkdown?

*(I'm open to using any other packages.)*

````
---
title: How to loop paged tables in Rmarkdown?
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---
   ```{r, echo=FALSE}

library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)
    ```
````

````
 ```{r,echo=FALSE, results='asis', rows.print=2}

lapply(unique(cars$speed), \(i){
  
cat(paste0("\n\n## ", i, "\n")) ## Writes new sections

Dat <- subset(cars, speed == i)

paged_table(Dat)  ## These paged tables don't show!

})
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the `paged_table(Dat)` line with this, it appears to work:

```
cat(rmarkdown:::paged_table_html(paged_table(Dat)))
```

Using the `rmarkdown` internal function `rmarkdown:::paged_table_html` is generally a somewhat bad idea, but I couldn't find another way to get this to output what you want.  This doesn't include the dependency normally added by `rmarkdown:::print.paged_df`, so you'll need at least one regular `paged_table()` in the document, or do some more work to get the dependency in there some other way.

There must be a cleaner way to do this.  Hopefully someone else will post it!